# How to generate a xslt file from xml

Tags: java, html, xslt, xhtml, xsl-fo

I'm beginner with xml and xsl. I'm looking for the way to generate or understanding how is the using of xsl stylesheet. In my particular case, I'm using a html file which it converts to xhtml. The next step I want to convert is the file generated to xsl-fo but I've seen I have to use a xslt stylesheet to do that. My question is about this file. How is it generate this xsl file? Is generated from the xhtml file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Antenna House provides a sample XHTML to XSL-FO stylesheet under the 'XHTML to XSL-FO' tab at http://www.antennahouse.com/antenna1/xml-to-xsl-fo-stylesheets/.  There's also an XSL-FO tutorial available under the 'XML to XSL-FO' tab.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the XSL file for an XSL-FO conversion is not generated. You'll have to create this file yourself. It contains a lot of information not present in the XHTML, for example page layouts.

XSL-FO is a bit like CSS, yes. The difference is that XSL-FO has lots more options, so an XSL-FO file is 100 times longer than a CSS file.

Here's an [introduction to XSL-FO](http://w3schools.sinsixx.com/xslfo/xslfo_intro.asp.htm).

And [another tutorial](http://www.renderx.com/tutorial.html).

Comment: I understand finally a xsl is file more or less like a css file?

Comment: It's possible referenciate inside a xslt file different css file like you can do with html files?

Comment: it should be, but I've never succeeded getting that to work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this site can give you some helps to generate xslfo [site](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xslfo2app/).
Abd if you wont the contrary this site is fine 
[XSL FO to HTML Converter](http://services.renderx.com/Content/tools/fo2html.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I look for al the contrary. From a html, I want to generate a xsl-fo file using Java.